# Find confidence interval in bivariate kernel estimation with Matlab

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, matlab

I'm executing this piece of code in order to estimate the probability density function of a bivariate set of random points:

```
x = [0+.5*rand(20,1) 5+2.5*rand(20,1);
        .75+.25*rand(10,1) 8.75+1.25*rand(10,1)];

figure
ksdensity(x);
```

and I wonder how to use the informations coming from the Matlab function `ksdensity` to evaluate the confidence interval I need.

My goal is to find outliers points in the set, namely that points that fall over the confidence interval.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check that link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html

Comment: @AboLregal I've read several times that page but unfortunately it seems not to provide any useful information about my issue. Anyhow thanks for trying!